# How can I create a (select image) like field inside django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, image, django-models

I am creating an order-app which enables the user to order custom name tags. I need to create a field that enables the user to select his/her desired background. Every background will have a key or id. I am currently representing this field using a PositiveIntegerField because there is going to be a 100 plus backgrounds so it is time-consuming to import them as choices inside a list.

```
from django.db import models
class Sticker(models.Model):
Lan = [
    ('ar', 'عربي'),
    ('en', 'English'),
]

name_field = models.CharField(max_length=40)
school_field = models.CharField(max_length=40)
grade_field = models.CharField(max_length=40)
quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
language = models.CharField(choices=Lan, max_length=2)
sticker_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
#image = models.ImageField(max_length=1, null= True)                                    
status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and this is how the form looks like, just used a simple ModelForm class to pass the fields.

```
from .models import Sticker, CustomerDetails, DeliveryDetails
class Meta:
    model = Sticker
    fields = ('name_field', 'school_field', 'grade_field', 'quantity', 'language', 'sticker_number')
```

So I need a way to show the user images and to be able to select an image. I am trying to build this project without using previously build templates or forms and I am still a beginner in python and django.